# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error in a custom view

Tags: 7, views

I wanted to display a table vertically and I found some code to do so, but I'm getting the following error:

```
warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in site/modules/views/theme/views-view-table.tpl.php on line 35.
```

Line 35 contains the following code: `<?php foreach($row['title'] as $title): ?>`.

If I comment out that line, the table stops to be displayed vertically. I read on drupal.org forums that modifying the user's view permissions was a way to resolve, but I granted all permissions to views and I am still getting the same error.

How can I avoid the error appears?

Comment: Could you post more of the code? foreach() normally interates over an array. Seems like $row['title'] is not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it..anyone using views hacks will need to nest the above statement in an php if statement to ensure there is data in the array.